# How do I persuade Mono to use Tls 1.2 or later?

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, centos6, tls1.2

I am running mono 5.4 (`mono -V` reports `Mono JIT compiler version 5.4.1.6 (tarball Wed Nov  8 17:02:20 UTC 2017)`) on `CentOS 6.9 (Final)`.

It was installed using the instructions at http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin-centos

I have a program that uses Stripe.net to talk to the Stripe credit card provider. But all transactions are rejected with the message `Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later. You can learn more about this at https://stripe.com/blog/upgrading-tls`.

I have written a test program to see if mono is using tls1.2, which includes an attempt to force it to do so:

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        File.WriteAllText("howsmyssl-httpclient.html", new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("https://www.howsmyssl.com").Result);
    }
}
```

When I look at the file, it says (amongst other things):

`Bad Your client is open to the BEAST attack. It's using TLS 1.0 or earlier while also supporting a cipher suite that uses Cipher-Block Chaining and doesn't implement the 1/n-1 record splitting mitigation. That combination will leak information.`

Is there some way of forcing the mono HttpClient to use TLS1.2?

Comment: Running your code on my mono 5.2 works fine (howsmyssl sais that my client is OK and supports TLS 1.2). Try to do `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_TLS_PROVIDER", "btls");`, though in my case it works without that.

Comment: I tried setting that environment variable, and it threw with `System.NotSupportedException: No such TLS Provider: "btls".`

Comment: Note that I compiled the code in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows, and copied the exe across. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Aha, so that is probably the reason. In docs they say that "our CentOS 6 packages still ship only the legacy TLS provider since the GCC on CentOS 6 is too old to compile BoringSSL". You are running CentOS 6 and I'm on CentOS 7. As for compiling from VS 2017 on windows - that's fine in 99% of cases (in this case too).

Comment: (and BoringSSL is that "btls" provider used by mono for TLS 1.2)

Comment: There is apparently a fix for boring ssl - https://github.com/mono/boringssl/issues/2. Plus the comment you quote is from the mono 4.8 release notes - does it still apply?

Comment: Yes it still applies. Mono packages for centos 6 do not include BoringSSL, because it needs to be compiled from sources, and GCC compiler which goes in centos 6 by default is too old to compile that. New versions of mono doesn't change which compiler version goes with CentOS 6. That doesn't mean it's not possible to compile that yourself (which guy from your link tries to do). Fix you mention just allows to skip building tests which helps with compiling with older version of GCC. So if you are stuck with CentOS 6 - you can follow this way and compile BoringSSL yourself.